# controlling stdin and stdout for an EXE fine from within python

Tags: python, exe, stdout, stdin

I have a file.exe, written by someone else, so I do not have the source code, nor do I have possibility to rewrite it. What the file.exe does is to open the ms-dos prompt, waits for 9 parameter to be provided as input via keyboard and then print text in the prompt (or in a text file if I want using file.exe > text.txt). I want to provide the imput parameter (stdin) from within a python script and read the stdout saving the output to a variable in python. Any chance to do it? I have done something simular with this instruction: `os.system('wine tp52win9x.exe < inputfile.txt > res.txt')` giving and writing from and to a txt file.

Comment: Just put 9 lines in `inputfile.txt` with one parameter on each line and see if that works.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have done it with the file inputfile.txt and it works. But I'd like to give the input directly from python variables

Comment: Ok, try `printf "%s\n" var1 var2 var3 ... | wine tp52win9x.exe` with `shell=True` ... you need that so the pipe `|` works.

Comment: Or `cmd = f'printf "%s\n" {var1} {var2} ... | wine ...'`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have tried this: "inp = ['1', '25', '19', '0.8', '2', '0.1', '3', '60', '3']
os.system('printf "%s\n" inp | wine tp52win9x.exe shell=True')" but I get the following error: "printf" not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @MarkSetchell could you give an example of how to type it in "os.system(...)"?

Comment: `shell=True` is a separate parameter, with a comma before it and not inside the quotes. What OS are you using?

Comment: Build the entire command in a string first, like I showed above, so you can print it and check it, then just run `os.system(cmd)`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell win 10

Comment: Oh! Why are you running under `wine` if already on Windows?

Comment: I do not know how it works, I am a newbie

Comment: Try `( echo 1; echo 25; echo 19; ... ) | wine tp52win9x.exe` in your Command Prompt.

Comment: @MarkSetchell wine command not recognized

Comment: Ok, try omitting `wine` but keeping all the rest.

Comment: the program exe starts. hower it gets only the firt input then I get this message
list in: end of file
 apparent state: unit 5 (unnamed)
last format: list io
lately reading sequential formatted external IO. Is there any way I can give the input as colums? n this way it should work

Comment: You could try `tp52win9x 1 25 19 ... 60 3`

Comment: Or `echo 1 25 19 ... 60 3 | tp52win9x`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Does `tp52win9x < file.txt` work if you put a single number on each line in `file.txt`

Comment: yes, this is what I have done before. I was hoping to do something similar via python. if I use var = os.system(file.name) I can run the exe from within python and giv ethe input via the terminal. so there must be a way to communicate with it

Comment: Do you get a file that you can use with `tp52win9x < file.txt` if you do `(echo 1; echo 25; echo 19; ...) > file.txt`